# How can I make VLC self-contained?

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, rss

I know that there is a PortableApp solution, but I am looking for an alternative solution.

I understand that VLC puts some of its preferences in AppData (for Windows OS) and I would like to have this info contained within VLC folder.

Specifically, I have my VLC downloaded on a USB and all my podcast subscriptions (RSS) get lost when I switch PC. I suspect that this information is being stored locally - causing me to lose it every time I switch PC.

Comment: You can always modify the source of VLC to change this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound, thank you. Does this mean that I download the source file and then compile on my own. Would it be possible if you could guide me as I am completely new to dealing with source files.

Comment: Try the pendriveapps version, https://pendriveapps.com/portable-vlc-media-player/

Comment: The zip file version from https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html is also portable.

Comment: "Would it be possible if you could guide me" - I don't provide programming help here at Superuser.

Comment: `PortableApp solution, but I am looking for an alternative solution` - Can you explain why?  It seems to me that would do exactly what you want?

Comment: @DavidPostill, the zip file is not portable as I still lose subscription information when I switch PC.